# Update an object properties using TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to dynamically update an object with option properties from an object. In the code, I'm getting an error where it says `axiosOptions.headers[key]` (I left a comment in the code example below).

## TypeScript Error

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"true" | "false"'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '"true" | "false"'.
```

## My Code

```
type ApiHeaders = {
  Accept: string;
  'Content-Type': string;
  IsRequireAdmin: 'true' | 'false';
  Authorization?: string;
  BarCode?: string;
  DomainName?: string;
};

interface AxiosOptions {
  params?: any;
  data?: any;
  headers: ApiHeaders;
}

const axiosOptions: AxiosOptions = {
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    IsRequireAdmin: 'false'
  }
};

const updateAxiosOptionsHeaders = (newApiHeaders: Partial<ApiHeaders>): void => {
  let key: keyof Partial<ApiHeaders>;
  for (key in newApiHeaders) axiosOptions.headers[key] = newApiHeaders[key]; // <----------- typescript error
};

const token: string = 'my_token';
const barCode: string = 'my_bar_code';
const domainName: string = 'www.mydomain.com';

const newApiHeaders: Omit<ApiHeaders, 'Content-Type' | 'Accept'> = {
  'IsRequireAdmin': 'true',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
  'BarCode': barCode,
  'DomainName': `DATA\\${domainName}`
  };

updateAxiosOptionsHeaders(newApiHeaders);
```

I'm open to suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: When it goes to set `IsRequireAdmin` it can't know that `newApiHeaders.IsRequireAdmin` is defined (since it's `Partial<ApiHeaders>` and not `ApiHeaders`). You'll have to decide whether to allow undefined as a possible value for `IsRequireAdmin`, or add a check to `updateAxiosOptionsHeaders` to validate that `newApiHeaders[key]` is defined.

Comment: @HereticMonkey if I do `(axiosOptions.headers as string | undefined | 'true' | 'false')[key] = newApiHeaders[key]`, I still get an error, but if I do `(axiosOptions.headers as any)[key] = newApiHeaders[key]`, then it works okay. I don't want to allow undefined for `IsRequiredAdmin`, so would you be able to elaborate more on your second suggestion into an answer?

Comment: Well `headers` isn't the thing that should be `string | undefined | 'true' | 'false'`; that's `headers[key]` that should be `string | undefined | 'true' | 'false'`. Casting it as `any` works because it no longer checks types at that point.

Comment: @HereticMonkey got it, thanks

Comment: Tangent to what's already been discussed: [TypeScript allows for objects with excess properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), so you'll also need to verify that every key iterated by the `in` operator is one of the keys that is expected. You can do that by deriving your types from an iterable data structure: [example](https://tsplay.dev/N7QAEW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't know what it doesn't know. It doesn't know what `key` will be in any given run of `updateAxiosOptionsHeaders` so it opts for the most restrictive possible interpretation. There are, of course, many different ways to fix the problem, but if you want to keep the types as they are, you can work around it in the function:

```
type ApiHeaders = {
  Accept: string;
  'Content-Type': string;
  IsRequireAdmin: 'true' | 'false';
  Authorization?: string;
  BarCode?: string;
  DomainName?: string;
};

interface AxiosOptions {
  params?: any;
  data?: any;
  headers: ApiHeaders;
}

const axiosOptions: AxiosOptions = {
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    IsRequireAdmin: 'false'
  }
};

const updateAxiosOptionsHeaders = (newApiHeaders: Partial<ApiHeaders>): void => {
  let key: keyof Partial<ApiHeaders>;
  for (key in newApiHeaders) {
    if (key === 'IsRequireAdmin') {
        // Note the default value if one isn't provided in newApiHeaders for some reason
        axiosOptions.headers.IsRequireAdmin = newApiHeaders.IsRequireAdmin ?? 'false';
    } else {
        // ditto here
        axiosOptions.headers[key] = newApiHeaders[key] ?? '';
    } 
  }
};
const token: string = 'my_token';
const barCode: string = 'my_bar_code';
const domainName: string = 'www.mydomain.com';

const newApiHeaders: Partial<ApiHeaders> = {
  'IsRequireAdmin': 'true',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
  'BarCode': barCode,
  'DomainName': `DATA\\${domainName}`
  };

updateAxiosOptionsHeaders(newApiHeaders);
```

See the comments on the changed parts; you'll need to decide on sensible default values.

Comment: Ah thank you, this catching way for an incorrect possible type is nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow for undefined. This is done when declaring the type not in the cast. See below.

```
type ApiHeaders = {
  Accept: string;
  'Content-Type': string;
  IsRequireAdmin: 'true' | 'false' | undefined;
  Authorization?: string;
  BarCode?: string;
  DomainName?: string;
};
```

Comment: unfortunately I also need to add undefined to all those types for this to work.